# Joomla stripping my iframe

Tags: html, joomla, joomla2.5

I was trying to embed the following video in an article using the JCE editor in Joomla 2.5:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/4vAJdrDb1eA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

However, either Joomla or JCE is stripping out the above code.

These are the steps I took to resolve this but was unsuccessful:

- In Joomla's *Text Filters* (Global Configuration), I set the *Super Users* (me) to *Custom Black List* as the filter type, and the following *Filter Tags* (I left out iframe):

> applet, body, bgsound, base,   basefont, embed, frame,frameset, head,
>   html, id,  ilayer, layer, link, meta, name, object, script, style,
>   title,  xml

- Next, in the JCE Administration Editor Global Configuration, I set
  *Validate HTML* (Cleanup & Output) = No

I saved all changes. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to allow iframe in Profles -> desired Profile -> Plugin parameters -> Allow IFrames.

Answer (score 1):

In JCE version 2.3.2.4, I found it on **Features and Layout** > **Additional Features** > **Media Support**

Answer (score 0):

just deactivate your editor when pasting code content, works always xD

and dont edit the article with an editor enabled and you should be fine. it was somehow easier in 1.5 to deactivete "code cleaning"....

Comment: Agree! just to ease the workaround you need, go to your user profile configuration and set the editor to NONE